# How do you open a new Mac OS X Terminal from Terminal and have it be in the same directory? (Snow Leopard)

Tags: macos, terminal

I want to open a new terminal window from my current window. (like command+n opens a new terminal window that is in the same directory from the window I spawned it in). This has always annoyed me so today I want to solve it.  Some bash script like

```
start /Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app -D CurrentDirectory
```

might work.

Also, my Lion machine does this automatically. I have Snow Leopard and I've searched through all the terminal preferences and the internet.

Comment: IMHO, the best solution to this is [tmux](http://tmux.sourceforge.net/) (which as of a recent release will do this for new shells even on OSX).

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Try:

```
open -a Terminal "`pwd`"
```

This works for me (on Lion) but provided you can run that command, it should work on Snow Leopard, I believe.

Comment: I got  open -a Terminal "'pwd'"
The file /Users/David/Desktop/'pwd' does not exist.

Comment: Make sure the inner single quotes are backticks (`), which is found on the tilde key at the upper left of my keyboard.

Comment: Yeah, It opens a new window but it goes to "process complete" so its not usable

Comment: `open -a Terminal .`

Comment: schurpf's suggestion works well here, and is less susceptible to the typing problems OP was having.

Comment: how open terminal with command "tail -f /var/log.log"?

Comment: This doesn't seem to work on OSX 10.12 (Sierra). It does open the terminal, but does not execute the command. For example - $ open -a Terminal "`echo $HOME`"  - just opens a new terminal but does not show the user's home directory.

Comment: @Jenkamen - I figured it out. 1) You need to create a bash script first containing your tail command -> #!/bin/bash  tail-f /var/log.log . 2) Make this file executable -> chmod +x myscript.sh . 3) Call this with the command above -> open -a Terminal myscript.sh

Comment: On macOS Mojave this opens Terminal but fails to run the `pwd` command.

Comment: Add this line to ~/.bash_profile:  alias terminal='open -a Terminal "`pwd`"'.  Reload your terminal and now you can run the alias terminal to do this.  Cheers 

Answer (score 3):

In your current Terminal window

> pwd | pbcopy

Command-N to create a new window

> cd "`pbpaste`"

The double quotes are necessary in case there is a space in your path, although I didn't test it.

The inner single quotes is the backtick character. It should work if you copy and paste the commands from my answer.

If you spend a lot of time in Terminal, consider using [iTerm 2](http://www.iterm2.com/). It's got some great enhancements over Apple's Terminal.app.

Comment: Thanks that helps, I could put the lines in commands so its now cw (closeWin), Command-n, ow (OpenWin) but its still sort of a pain. I'll also look into iTerm2.  Any ideas on how to make it one complete command (automater ?)